# fetch() with cross domain cause JSON.parse error

Tags: cors, fetch

I'm trying to use fetch() with cross domain, but I'm getting unusual errors.  I have the following script hosted on `http://example2.com/index.html`

```
let url = "https://example1.com/login";
fetch(url,
        {
        "method":"POST",
        "content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "mode":"no-cors",
        "headers":{
                "Authorization":"Basic johnjohn",
                "Auth-Secret":"johnsecretpassword",
        }
})
.then(response=>response.text())
.then(content=>{
        console.log(content); // prints empty line
        json = JSON.parse(content);
})
.catch(e=>console.log(`Error occurred: ${e}`));
```

When I run this script, my `console.log(content)` prints an empty line and my `JSON.parse(content)` gives a `Error occurred: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` error.

When I go to FireFox developer console, click on network, click on response, I do see the following payload:

[image]

Changing the `response.text()` to `response.json()` triggers the `catch` block with the same JSON parse error.

Also, my `https://example1.com/login` is a php file with the following content:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Auth-Secret, Content-Type');

die(json_encode(array("data"=>"authorization","status"=>"fail")));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` with authorization credentials.  The domain name must explicitly be specified if credentials are used.

Comment: I tried renaming the `Authorization` to `Blah1` and `Auth-Secret` to `Blah2` in both my PHP script and JavaScript fetch().  But I still get the same error.   Shouldn't Blah1 and Blah2 allowed me to bypass whatever default authorization process is used by the server side or client side?

Comment: CORS won't allow non-standard headers unless you explicitly permit them, but I don't think it would reject the request; it would simply deny access to those headers.  See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests) on CORS permitted headers.

Comment: Thanks, I added `header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Auth-Secret, Content-Type');` to my PHP script, but still same issue.  I'll have to research this again tomorrow. Oh, and the problem doesn't exist when both the PHP script and the javascript are on the same top level domain with SSL.

Comment: and this problem doesn't exist with Postman...I get a success end-to-end usage with postman

Comment: Postman is not restricted by the Same Origin policy, so CORS doesn't apply at all.  Your last two comments confirm this is caused by CORS.

Comment: I just noticed that you have `"mode":"no-cors",`.  I think this should be "cors"

Comment: I just deleted the `"mode":"no-cors"` all together because it's on by default.  In conjunction with my new `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, everything works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Amy in my comments above.  These two changes fixed the problem:

I added this line to my `login.php`:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Auth-Secret, Content-Type');
```

And I deleted the line `"mode":"no-cors"` in my `index.html`.

This way, my `index.html` will respect CORS and my `login.php` is ready to access the other headers.